# I need to create a for loop that generates nested dictionaries

Tags: python

I need to create a for loop that generates a new nested dictionary each time a key that does not already exist is detected. I am getting the info for the outer dictionary's from a previous function.

- It will need to create a dictionary with the available sports as its keys and a dictionary as its
  value.
- Within the inner dictionary, the athlete name will be used as its key and the number of medals
  (integer) will be its value.
  Key = Sport, Value = {: }
  CSE 231 Spring 2019
- The function will loop through the dictionary from get_country_stats() to find the
  athlete, sport and medal. Note that when you want to add an athlete for a new sport you need
  to first create an empty dictionary for that sport before you can add an athlete to it.
- The type of medal (gold, silver, bronze) is not relevant for our new dictionary, they will all be
  treated as 1 medal.

I've initiated two empty dictionaries, the outer and inner ones. Then created an outer for loop that goes through all the key value pairs and returns a list

```
def display_best_athletes_per_sport(Athlete, Country, Sports):
    medals = 0
    outer_dict = {}
    inner_dict = {}
    for key, value in Country.items(): 
        for item in value:
            athlete = item[0]
            medals = item[5]
            sport = item[3]
            inner_dict = {athlete:medals}
            outer_dict = {sport:inner_dict}
        if sport not in outer_dict:
            new_dict[sport] = value[i]
            if medals in value:
                medals += 1
            else:
                medals = 1
```

I want to be able to generate a new outer dictionary if the desired key(sport) isn't found, tthen update the inner dictionary's value each time a medal is found for a specific athlete.

this is the output from the Country function that is being used in the function im trying to make now:

```
{'FIN': [
    ('Juhamatti Tapio Aaltonen', 'Finland', 2014, 'ice hockey', "ice hockey men's ice hockey", 'bronze'),
    ('Paavo Johannes Aaltonen', 'Finland', 1948, 'gymnastics', "gymnastics men's individual all-around", 'bronze'),
    ('Paavo Johannes Aaltonen', 'Finland', 1948, 'gymnastics', "gymnastics men's team all-around", 'gold'),
    ('Paavo Johannes Aaltonen', 'Finland', 1948, 'gymnastics', "gymnastics men's horse vault", 'gold'),
    ('Paavo Johannes Aaltonen', 'Finland', 1948, 'gymnastics', "gymnastics men's pommelled horse", 'gold'),
    ('Paavo Johannes Aaltonen', 'Finland', 1952, 'gymnastics', "gymnastics men's team all-around", 'bronze')],
'NOR': [
    ('Kjetil Andr Aamodt', 'Norway', 1992, 'alpine skiing', "alpine skiing men's super g", 'gold'),
    ('Kjetil Andr Aamodt', 'Norway', 1992, 'alpine skiing', "alpine skiing men's giant slalom", 'bronze'),
    ('Kjetil Andr Aamodt', 'Norway', 1994, 'alpine skiing', "alpine skiing men's downhill", 'silver'),
    ('Kjetil Andr Aamodt', 'Norway', 1994, 'alpine skiing', "alpine skiing men's super g", 'bronze'),
    ('Kjetil Andr Aamodt', 'Norway', 1994, 'alpine skiing', "alpine skiing men's combined", 'silver'),
    ('Kjetil Andr Aamodt', 'Norway', 2002, 'alpine skiing', "alpine skiing men's super g", 'gold'),
    ('Kjetil Andr Aamodt', 'Norway', 2002, 'alpine skiing', "alpine skiing men's combined", 'gold'),
    ('Kjetil Andr Aamodt', 'Norway', 2006, 'alpine skiing', "alpine skiing men's super g", 'gold'),
    ('Ann Kristin Aarnes', 'Norway', 1996, 'football', "football women's football", 'bronze')],
'NED': [('Pepijn Aardewijn', 'Netherlands', 1996, 'rowing', "rowing men's lightweight double sculls", 'silver')]}
```

Comment: Do you have some sample data and expected output?

Comment: It would be helpful to include a sample output of `get_country_stats()` so we could provide more relevant responses

Comment: @Reedinationer okay sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow!

Comment: Some suggestions:  1) Don't user uppercase words for variable names.  Reserve those for class and other type names.  2) with `outer_dict = {sport:inner_dict}`, you're clobbering your whole data structure for each item you process.  3) if **sport** is defined, it will always be in **outer_dict**, so your second **if** will never do anything except crash in the case where you didn't process any items.

Comment: @Steve the uppercase parameters were already provided by our instructor. Thank you for the suggestions, I will make the changes.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting.  Not a good practice on the part of the instructor to promote going against standard naming conventions.

Comment: @Steve okay maybe i can make the question less specific and then mold my function based on a more general suggestions and start from scratch. So how would one go about generating nested dictionaries by looping through data? I want to create a brand new outer dictionary if the data isnt already found in a previous iteration

Comment: @AlexiaHenderson To be clear: your expected output is a `dict` with sports' names as keys and an inner `dict` as values, where the inner `dict` has athletes' names as keys and number of total medals as values, right?

Comment: @gmds correct thats exactly what i need to do

Comment: @Alexia, I like that you've gotten this far.  You're really trying...I can tell that.  Good for you.  Let's help you...

Comment: The first big idea I see is that you start by creating an empty **outer_dict** with nothing in it.  This is common.  So what you want to do is always **add** entries to that dictionary.  So think in terms of testing for a key to be in that dictionary already, and then adding an entry with that key if it isn't there yet. - a lot of what you have here already is god.

Comment: Another issue I see is that you extract a **sport** for each item you process in your inner **for** loop, but then the **if** that follows is outside that loop.  I'm guessing that you want the **if** to be inside the inner **for** loop. - But again, I don't see the **if** making sense in either case given that you always create an item with `outer_dict = {sport:inner_dict}` just above that.  So it seems that **outer_dict** should already have a **sport** key in it by that poinnt.

Comment: @AlexiaHenderson I agree with @Steve. What are `Athlete` and Sports` for, though? They aren't used in the function.

Comment: @gmds so this section of assignment contains multiple parts, Athlete and Sports are used in a later part. Could I upload this section of directions to this page to make this process easier for us all? That way you guys can read for yourself the chaos lol

Comment: @folks, do you think it's good for me to give her the code for the basic idea here?  I think she's trying, and a few lines of code couldn't hurt?

Comment: @Steve IMO, the only answer to provide here (per SO rules) is a full one that adheres as much as possible to the intention of the asker - so nothing fancy like `itertools.groupby`. I would say it's up to the asker to make the most of the given answer by actually thinking about how it works, rather than just handing it in/pushing it/etc..

Comment: @gmds, I don't understand what you're saying. Are you commenting on a comment of mine above, or my answer?  I don't think I suggested anything that goes against what you are saying here, in either case.

Comment: @gmds,  If you're speaking to my answer...I'm not doing anything fancy, or using any external modules.  All I'm suggesting is breaking up the two acts of a) making sure that a place exists in the structure for the data, and b) adding the actual data.  I think this actually makes it easier to "think about how it works".  It allows two problems to be dealt with in the code individually.  I consider it cleaner code structure, nothing more.  We're doing things at the same "level".

Comment: @Steve no, not at all - if I had thought that I would have commented on your answer. Rather, I was responding to your mention of "a few lines of code"; I took that to mean that you were suggesting a partial answer. Sorry if I gave you the wrong impression!

Comment: Ah, cool.  No worries. - I guess I meant "a few NEW lines of code amidst her existing code" :) . I totally agree with your intent here.  Just didn't pick up on it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the cat's out of the bag now. So here's my take on this.  I think it's good to separate checking for an entry to appear in a dict from adding something to that entry.  So when you add the entry, it always "has nothing in it yet".  This lets you treat "adding the next item to the entry" in the same way regardless of if the entry exists or not.  Given that, here's the basic idea of what you want to do, as I see it:

```
def display_best_athletes_per_sport(Athlete, Country, Sports):
    outer_dict = {}
    for key, value in Country.items():
        for item in value:
            athlete = item[0]
            medals = item[5]
            sport = item[3]
            if sport not in outer_dict:
                outer_dict[sport] = {}
            if athlete not in outer_dict[sport]:
                outer_dict[sport][athlete] = 0
            outer_dict[sport][athlete] += 1
    pprint(outer_dict)
```

and here's the result:

```
{'alpine skiing': {'Kjetil Andr Aamodt': 8},
 'football': {'Ann Kristin Aarnes': 1},
 'gymnastics': {'Paavo Johannes Aaltonen': 5},
 'ice hockey': {'Juhamatti Tapio Aaltonen': 1},
 'rowing': {'Pepijn Aardewijn': 1}}
```

This is the same as the answer @gmds provides, so both are valid ways to attack the problem, and do so quite similarly.

Comment: Note that although the two answers are roughly the same, the order is different.  In general, across all computing, any data structure based on a HashMap will not be sorted in any way...you can't rely on the order in which you retrieve the values.

Comment: @alexia231, there's an idea that I think is valuable for you to see here.  You'll do this basic thing over and over again as you program more and more.  See how I make sure that the various "buckets" exist for data without really adding the data?  This is seen by the fact that `outer_dict[sport][athlete] += 1` is always called.  So there's only a single way that the actual data you have is being added to the structure.  I think this is a valuable construction technique to get.  When your code gets more complex, this will simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```py
# Define these magic numbers outside so it's clearer what we're doing inside the function.

ATHLETE_INDEX = 0
SPORT_INDEX = 3

def display_best_athletes_per_sport(Athlete, Country, Sports):
    result = {}
    for country_name, athlete_data in Country.items():
        for athlete_datum in athlete_data:
            athlete = athlete_datum [ATHLETE_INDEX]
            sport = athlete_datum [SPORT_INDEX]

            if sport in result:
                if athlete in result[sport]:
                    result[sport][athlete] += 1  # Just add 1 to the number of medals for this athlete and sport.

                else:
                    result[sport][athlete] = 1  # This athlete has no medals for this sport, but the sport already exists. Create a new key for the athlete.

            else:
                result[sport] = {athlete: 1}  # Both the sport and athlete don't exist yet, so we initialise an inner dictionary.

    return result
```

Output on provided data:

```
{'ice hockey': {'Juhamatti Tapio Aaltonen': 1},
 'gymnastics': {'Paavo Johannes Aaltonen': 5},
 'alpine skiing': {'Kjetil Andr Aamodt': 8},
 'football': {'Ann Kristin Aarnes': 1},
 'rowing': {'Pepijn Aardewijn': 1}}
```

Comment: @gmds, I do see a small problem here.  What's the thinking with the line `result[sport] = 1`?  Doesn't this mean you're going to end up with a map that for some keys includes another map as a value, and for other keys includes an integer value?  I think that's not a good thing. - given that that case doesn't show up in the output, I guess it never occurs.

Comment: @Steve Good catch, that's my bad.

Comment: @gmds does a good thing by abstracting the index values into constant labels ATHLETE_INDEX and SPORT_INDEX!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit more condensed version that highlights the value of the `get()` method of Python dictionaries:

```
final = {}

for abb, data in Country.items():
    for i in data:
        final[i[3]] = final.get(i[3], {i[0]: 0})
        final[i[3]][i[0]] += 1
```

First, we instantiate an empty dictionary `final` for our output. We then iterate through your `Country` dictionary (side note, you should reserve using capitalized variable names for classes) and then through each entry for a given country. The first line in the nested for loop ensures that an inner dictionary is created for the sport in question if it does not already exist, where the second line in the nested for loop captures the incremental addition of medals portion of your question.

The code above produces:

```
{
 'ice hockey': {'Juhamatti Tapio Aaltonen': 1},
 'gymnastics': {'Paavo Johannes Aaltonen': 5},
 'alpine skiing': {'Kjetil Andr Aamodt': 8},
 'football': {'Ann Kristin Aarnes': 1},
 'rowing': {'Pepijn Aardewijn': 1}
}
```